# Prove that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2(n-1)}{2^n} = 20$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation, power-series

This sum  $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2(n-1)}{2^n} $showed up as I was computing the expected value of a random variable.
My calculator tells me that  $\,\,\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2(n-1)}{2^n} = 20$.
How can I show that?

I know how to find the value of the sum $\,\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2}{2^n},\,$ but I can't deal with $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^3}{2^n}$

Comment: What is your method for the expression with $n^2$ in the numerator?

Comment: @Travis use the identity $n^2=n(n-1)+n$ and power series.

Comment: OP: Then my answer should be reduced to $$n^2(n−1)=2⋅n(n−1)+n(n−1)(n−2).$$

Comment: @Did yes, it's the only line I read. Thanks for detailing anyway, it may benefit less experienced people.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Note that $\sum\limits_nt^n=\frac1{1-t}$ for every $|t|\lt1$ hence, differentiating this twice and three times, $$\sum_nn(n-1)t^{n-2}=\frac2{(1-t)^3},\qquad\sum_nn(n-1)(n-2)t^{n-3}=\frac6{(1-t)^4}.$$ For $t=\frac12$, this reads $$\sum_nn(n-1)\frac1{2^{n-2}}=2\cdot2^3,\qquad\sum_nn(n-1)(n-2)\frac1{2^{n-3}}=6\cdot2^4,$$ which implies $$\sum_nn(n-1)\frac1{2^{n}}=\frac14\cdot2\cdot2^3=\color{red}{4},\qquad\sum_nn(n-1)(n-2)\frac1{2^{n}}=\frac18\cdot6\cdot2^4=\color{blue}{12}.$$ Finally, $$n^2(n-1)=\color{green}{2}\cdot n(n-1)+n(n-1)(n-2),$$ hence $$\sum_nn^2(n-1)\frac1{2^{n}}=\color{green}{2}\cdot\sum_nn(n-1)\frac1{2^{n}}+\sum_nn(n-1)(n-2)\frac1{2^{n}}=\color{green}{2}\cdot\color{red}{4}+\color{blue}{12}.$$ This approach can be made shorter if one notices once and for all that, for every nonnegative $k$, $$\sum_nn(n-1)\cdots(n-k)\frac1{2^{n}}=2\cdot(k+1)!.$$

Comment: you wrote for every $|t|<1$ what is in the case $t=0$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Your comment is quite cryptic but I presume you are alluding to $n-2$ and $n-3$ as powers of $t$ in the derivatives of the series for $1/(1-t)$. If you look carefully at the series involved you will note that every power $t^k$ with $k\lt0$ has coefficient $0$. For example, in the second derivative, $t^{n-2}$ causes no problem for $n=0$ or $n=1$ since then $n(n-1)=0$. Hence the series are well defined (at least) for every $|t|\lt1$. This is entirely standard.

Answer (score 11):

For $\lvert x\rvert<1$ we have that
$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\frac{1}{1-x},$
hence differentiating both sides we get
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)x^{n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2},
$$
while differentiating once more
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+2)(n+1)x^{n}=\frac{2}{(1-x)^3},
$$
and once again
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+3)(n+2)(n+1)x^{n}=\frac{6}{(1-x)^4}.
$$
Next, we express $n^2(n-1)$ as a linear combination of
$(n+3)(n+2)(n+1)$, $(n+2)(n+1)$, $(n+1)$ and $1$:
$$
n^2(n-1)=(n+3)(n+2)(n+1)-7(n+2)(n+1)+10(n+1)-2,
$$
and hence
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^2(n-1)x^n=\frac{6}{(1-x)^4}-\frac{14}{(1-x)^3}+\frac{10}{(1-x)^2}-\frac{2}{1-x},
$$
and setting $x=1/2$ we obtain that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n^2(n-1)}{2^n}=6\cdot 16-4\cdot 8+10\cdot 4-4=20.
$$

Comment: Please don't make nonessential changes to the question. One might think that you are simply trying to bring the question to the front page without really improving the question or adding a bounty.

Answer (score 3):

prove by induction that
$\sum_{n=1}^m\frac{n^2(n-1)}{2^n}=-4\, \left( 1/2 \right) ^{m+1} \left( m+1 \right) ^{2}-14\, \left( 1/2
 \right) ^{m+1} \left( m+1 \right) -20\, \left( 1/2 \right) ^{m+1}-2\,
 \left( 1/2 \right) ^{m+1} \left( m+1 \right) ^{3}+20
$

Comment: How did you guess that ?

Comment: try it and i have somes books and scripts

Comment: What are the downvotes for?

Comment: take the limit for $m->\infty$ and you will get the answer for your question

Comment: What is the use of computing the value of every partial sum when only their (much simpler) limit is asked for?

Comment: @Did it is you who says what is much easier. Before the solution you can't see it.

Comment: @Lolman Sorry? You do not believe the complete sum is easier? Wow...

Comment: @Did Did OP ask for the simplest solution to compute the sum?To compute each partial sum and then its limit is the definition of the infinite sum, and thus can always be of use, I believe.

Comment: @awllower I am surprised by your surprise with the downvotes. There are two reasons why this answer is not useful. First it makes believe that it would be necessary to compute every partial sum to reach the value of the sum of the series. This is not so, and no mathematician would go this way to compute the sum of the series. To exhibit the (relatively intricate) formula for the partial sums can only help persuade the OP that the exercise is too difficult for them (but it probably makes the answerer happy with themselves). Second there is no explanation about how the formula was computed.

Comment: Well, I am not surprised by the downvote, but I don't think so bad of this answer. First, how can you be sure what mathematicians would do, and would not do? Also, it does not make believe that such an approach is *necessary*, as no approach really is necessary, at all. It simply provides with a viewpoint, maybe unorthodox. Second, indeed this answer is in dearth of explanations, but can be fixed if the answerer posts his thoughts and attempts and guesses on this. In any case, what "surprised" me is the downvote without a suggestion on how to improve upon the answer. Anyways, thanks for your..

Comment: ..attention. P.S. What I want to say is: If this answer is not good enough, tell us why, please, and thanks.

Comment: @awllower "how can you be sure what mathematicians would do, and would not do?" Simple answer: I am one of them and I know a few of them and the exchanges I have had with them on similar matters were unambiguous. (So, yes, just a sample, but 100%.) More elaborate answer: because the "nice" object is often the sum of the full series, not its partial sums. To keep things simple, consider $s(t)=\sum\limits_nt^n$ and $s_N(t)=\sum\limits_{n\leqslant N}t^n$, then $s(t)=1+ts(t)$ while there is no such simple identity for $s_N(t)$ (true, $s_N(t)=1+ts_{N-1}(t)$, but nothing with $s_N(t)$ only). .../...

Comment: .../... Thus $s(t)$ is the mathematical object easy to work with in this context, the one with the most inner structure. // "It simply provides with a viewpoint, maybe unorthodox" On this I have to disagree. Implicit in every math.se answer is the assumption that the method presented is a good/natural/interesting approach. Otherwise, when a user presents an exotic line of analysis and they know there is another, canonical, one, they insert some caveat such as "This is not the most direct way but one can note that..." Here we have a user insisting that they are a "Dr." but presenting .../...

Comment: .../... a bad method (not "unorthodox", thank you, just bad) without ever mentioning it is at most of an anecdotal interest. // Finally, about the possible fixes to the answer and the lack of comments by downvoters, you are right in principle but you might want to consider the context: in the recent period this user rapidly posted numerous mediocre answers, all without the slightest explanation, and never reacted to comments asking for explanations. Quite a few of them are now deleted but, as you know, regarding downvotes, such a context counts. (Unrelated: Please use @.)

Comment: @awllower To conclude, maybe this is just me but the exchange "Q.: How did you guess that ? – A.: try it and i have somes books and scripts" simply cannot be excused.

Comment: @Did I don't think the "cnotext" matters at all: why should one judge a post by its poster, not by its content? In addition, I provide (my) explanation of the identity in the answer below. Thanks for your opinion, in any case.

Comment: @awllower So, to top it all, the Doctor's formula is even **wrong**? Or did I misunderstand your post? (Anyway, I am not sure to get the point of the last (semi-hidden, mentioning my username) remark in your answer, but, since the same basically applies to this whole exchange, it might be better to stop here.)

Comment: @Did I didn't check the formulas, so I am not sure if that is wrong, but that form is not so clear. BTW, that remark serves only to explain an opinion, that partial sums are of a role no less important than that of its limits; in any case, I agree that it might be better to stop here. :)

Answer (score 3):

Say $f(x) = \sum_0^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{2^n} = \frac{1}{1-\tfrac{x}{2}}$. The first three derivatives of $f$ will be linear combinations of $a_k(x)=\sum^{\infty} \frac{n^k x^n}{2^n}$ for $k=1...3$ and are easy to calculate using $f$'s closed form.

Solve your system of equations in $a_k$ and you can compute your sum.

Answer (score 2):

I like the triangle sum technique:

Take for instance:

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2}{2^n}$

$\frac{1}{2}+2\cdot\frac{1}{4}+3\cdot\frac{1}{8}+...=\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{2^n}=2$

$\hspace{20pt} 2\cdot\frac{1}{4}+3\cdot\frac{1}{8}+...=\frac{1}{2}{\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n+1}{2^n}}=\frac{1}{2}{\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{2^n}+\frac{1}{2^n}}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot (2+1)$

$\hspace{53pt} 3\cdot\frac{1}{8}+...$=$\frac{1}{4}{\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n+2}{2^n}}$=$\frac{1}{4}{\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{2^n}+2\cdot\frac{1}{2^n}}=\frac{1}{4}\cdot (2+2)$

$\hspace{100pt} .......$

$ 2+\frac{1}{2}\cdot (2+1)+\frac{1}{4}\cdot (2+2)+...=\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2+n}{2^n}=2\cdot \displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n}+\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{2^n}=4+2=6$

Try it now?

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^3}{2^n}$

$\frac{1}{2}+4\cdot\frac{1}{4}+9\cdot\frac{1}{8}+...=\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2}{2^n}$

$\hspace{20pt} 4\cdot\frac{1}{4}+9\cdot\frac{1}{8}+...=\frac{1}{2}{\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(n+1)^2}{2^n}}$

$\hspace{53pt} 9\cdot\frac{1}{8}+...=\frac{1}{4}{\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(n+2)^2}{2^n}}$

Hint: 
$\displaystyle \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^m}\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(n+m)^2}{2^n}$

Answer (score 0):

As this post is intended to justify the answer of @Dr.Sonnhard Graubner, I make this CW.
The starting points are that, defining $S_k(m)=\sum_{n=1}^m\frac{n^k}{2^n},$ we can easily compute $S_0(m)$ and $S_k(1),$ and that we can use recursive relations to obtain $S_3(m)$ from $S_0(m)$ and $S_3(1).$
Thus we divide the post into four steps:
**I.** $k=0$
$S_0(m)=\sum_{n=1}^m\frac{1}{2^n}=1-\frac{1}{2^m}$ (Geometric series)
**II.** $k=1$
Since $S_1(m)-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}(\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}\frac{n+1}{2^n})=\frac{1}{2}S_1(m-1)+\frac{1}{2}S_0(m-1),$ we find that $S_1(m)=\frac{1}{2}S_1(m-1)+1-2^{-m}=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{2}S_1(m-2)+1-2^{-m+1})+1-2^{-m}=\cdots=\frac{1}{2^{m-1}}S_1(1)+\sum_{n=0}^{m-2}\frac{1}{2^{n}}(1-\frac{1}{2^{m-n}})=\frac{1}{2^m}+\frac{1-(1/2)^{m-1}}{1/2}-\frac{(m-1)}{2^m}=2-\frac{1}{2^m}(m+2).$
**III.** $k=2$
By similar token, one finds the recursive relation $S_2(m)=\frac{1}{2}S_2(m-1)+3-\frac{2m+3}{2^m}.$ Then we deduce the formular for $S_2(m):$
$$S_2(m)=\frac{1}{2^m}+\sum_{n=0}^{m-2}\frac{1}{2^n}(3-\frac{2(m-n)+3}{2^{m-n}})=\frac{1}{2^m}+6-\frac{12}{2^m}-\frac{1}{2^m}(m^2+4m-5)$$$$=6-\frac{1}{2^m}(m^2+4m+6).$$
**IV.** $k=3$
Again we have the resursive relation $S_3(m)=\frac{1}{2}S_3(m)+13-\frac{1}{2^m}(3m^2+9m+13),$ from which we deduce the formula:
$$S_3(m)=\frac{1}{2^{m-1}}S_3(1)+\sum_{n=0}^{m-2}\frac{1}{2^n}(13-\frac{3(m-n)^2+9(m-n)+13}{2^{m-n}})$$
$$=\cdots=\frac{1}{2^m}+26-\frac{52}{2^m}-\frac{m^3+6m^2+18m-25}{2^m}=26-\frac{m^3+6m^2+18m+26}{2^m}.$$
Here the dots mean a process of simplification.
Hence we see that $\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}S_3(m)-S_2(m)=26-6=20.$
So I am wondering where do those $(1/2)^{m+1}$ terms in the answer by @Dr.Sonnhard Graubner appear.

> Finally I would like to say something, in reply to @Did: Indeed no simple functional equation holds for $S_k(m),$ but one doesn't expect there to be one at all: instead one looks for a recursive relation, to which one is used in dealing with discrete relations, such as finding the partial sums.

Hope this helps still.

Answer (score 0):

As hinted by @AlexandreHalm,
 $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k=\frac1{1-x}.$$

Then deriving on $x$ and multiplying by $x$,

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty kx^k=\frac x{(1-x)^2},$$
 $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty k^2x^k=\frac{2x^2}{(1-x)^3}+\frac x{(1-x)^2},$$
 $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty k^3x^k=\frac{6x^3}{(1-x)^4}+\frac{6x^2}{(1-x)^3}+\frac x{(1-x)^2}.$$

Evaluating at $x=\frac12$,

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{k^3}{2^k}-\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{k^2}{2^k}=26-6=20.$$